# How do I deploy salesforce Apex code programmatically using metadataAPI?

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata-api, deployment-api

I am developing an application that is supposed to connect with clients' salesforce accounts and deploy some apex code to them. I am doing this in Groovy - but Java works same.

After looking at the tutorial on how to go about that [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm), I want to ask if there is a way to use the clients' access token gotten from the OAuth flow instead of using their username and password?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. If you have already OAuth token which is SessionId returned by SOAP Login call, you can just use OAuth token directly without making additional login call passing credentials to it.